Is there any formula to calculate difference between two timings when both timings are from different dates?
I am working on a dataset which contains the date and time of the cars issued for rent and then date and time of the returning cars. I am looking for a formula which can help me find the duration between these two dates and time. I am looking for total number of days and hours.
I have split the dates and time of the starting period and final period. Then I have calculated difference between dates and time. This way amount of days have been calculated separately and number of hours have been calculated separately. Then by combining both I can have the total time period. I am just wondering if there is any formula which can calculate the entire thing in one go rather split the dates and time.

Please decide if you use MySQL or Google-Bigquery and fix the tags accordingly. If you use multiple RDBMS, create separate questions for each of them.

Why do you separate date and time? Use a DATETIME column to combine them, and just subtract.

Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios and show the result you want to achieve - all as editable text, appropriately formatted

Removed conflicting product tags, please add the one back that you actually use!

Try DATETIME_DIFF(column1, Column2) that would get you the results you needed in Integer format.
for example DATETIME_DIFF(check_in, check_out) results would be 6.
check_in : 2024/04/04
check_out : 2024/04/10

Please read the question more carefully. They want to get both toal days and total hours in one function call.

Also note that DATE_DIFF is a product specific function, and OP hasn't told which dbms is used.
